# $a_{m, n}$ is coefficient of $x^n$ in expansion $(1+x+x^2)^m.$ Prove $0\leq \sum_{i = 0}^{\left\lfloor 2k/3\right\rfloor} (-1)^ia_{k-i,i} \leq 1$

Tags: contest-math, generating-functions, multinomial-theorem

Problem Statement: Let $a_{m, n}$ denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion $(1+x+x^2)^m.$ Prove that for all $k\geq 0$,
$$0\leq \sum_{i = 0}^{\left\lfloor 2k/3\right\rfloor} (-1)^ia_{k-i,i} \leq 1$$

I first tried to find a good expression for $a_{m, n}$. We note that if $w = e^{2\pi i/3}$ then $(1+x+x^2)^m = (x-w)^m(x-w^{-1})$
\begin{align}
a_{m, n} &= [x^n]\left(\sum_{a = 0}^m\binom{m}{a}(-w)^{m-a}x^a\right)\left(\sum_{b = 1}^m\binom{m}{b}(-w)^{m-b}x^b\right)\\
&=\sum_{a+b = n}\binom{m}{a}\binom{m}{b}(-w)^{n-a-(n-b)}\\
&= \sum_{a = 0}^m\binom{m}{a}\binom{m}{n-a}(-w)^{n-2a}\\
&= \sum_{a = 0}^m(-1)^{n - 2a}\binom{m}{a}^2 w^{n-2a}
\end{align}

Thus we have:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{\left\lfloor 2k/3\right\rfloor} (-1)^ia_{k-i,i} &= \sum_{i = 0}^{\left\lfloor 2k/3\right\rfloor} (-1)^i\left(\sum_{a = 0}^{k-i}(-1)^{i - 2a}\binom{k-i}{a}^2 w^{i-2a}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i = 0}^{\left\lfloor 2k/3\right\rfloor}\sum_{a = 0}^{k-i}\binom{k-i}{a}^2 w^{i-2a}
\end{align}

From here I'm stuck as to how I should proceed. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please state explicitly the source of the problem.

Comment: In case my previous comment was confusing, I intended: from what contest is this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $a_{k,n} = a_{k, n-1 } + a_{k-1, n-1} + a_{k-2, n-1}$.
$a_{k,n} - a_{k+1,n} =a_{k-2,n-1} - a_{k+1, n}$.

Use this recursively to reduce terms till you're done

E.g. $a_{4,0} - a_{3,1} + a_{2,2}  \\
=a_{3,-2} + a_{3,-1} + a_{3,0} - a_{3,1} - a_{2,2} \\
= a_{3,0} - a_{3,1} - a_{2,2} \\
= a_{2,-2} - a_{2,1} + a_{2,2} \\
= - a_{2,1} + a_{2,2}  \\
= -a_{1,-1} + a_{1,2} \\
= 0$

Answer (score 0):

We have $a_{k-i,i}=[x^i](1+x+x^2)^{k-i}=[x^k](x+x^2+x^3)^{k-i}$, thus $$A_k:=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor 2k/3\rfloor}(-1)^ia_{k-i,i}\\=[x^k]\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor 2k/3\rfloor}(-1)^i(x+x^2+x^3)^{k-i}=(-1)^k[x^k]\sum_{s=k-\lfloor 2k/3\rfloor}^{k}(-1)^s(x+x^2+x^3)^{s}.\tag{1}$$
Note that $[x^k](x+x^2+x^3)^s=0$ whenever $s>k$ or $s<k/3$. If $s<k-\lfloor 2k/3\rfloor$, then $s\leqslant k-1-\lfloor 2k/3\rfloor<k/3$, so the right hand side of $(1)$ does not change if we extend the summation to all values of $s=0,1,2,\ldots$ and get $$A_k=(-1)^k[x^k]\sum_{s=0}^\infty (-1)^s(x+x^2+x^3)^s=(-1)^k[x^k]\frac1{1+x+x^2+x^3}=(-1)^k[x^k]\frac{1-x}{1-x^4}.$$
Expanding $1/(1-x^4)=1+x^4+x^8+\ldots$ we see that $A_k=0$ for $k$ congruent to 2 or 3 modulo 4 and $A_k=1$ for $k$ congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4.